# Using a vector to index a data.frame in R

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I have a data.frame which contains an ID number and scaled responses from a survey:

```
df(responses)

ID    X1    X2    X3    X4
A1    1     1     2     1
B2    0     1     3     0
C3    3     3     2     0
```

I also have a data.frame that is used as a key:

```
df(key)

X    Y    Z
2    1    1
3    2    2
4    3    4
```

I am trying to write a script that will calculate an `X`, `Y`, and `Z` score for each participant, where the `X` score is the sum of the responses for the questions listed under `X` in the key.

e.g. the `X` score for participant `A1` would be equal to the sum of `X2`, `X3`, and `X4`in the `A1` row `(1+2+1 = 4)`.

The desired output is:

```
df(output)

ID    X    Y    Z
A1    4    4    3
B2    4    4    1
C3    5    8    6
```

However, I am currently struggling to be able to index the data.frame `responses` using the values in `key`. My current state is:

```
#store scale names
scales <- c(colnames(key))
#loop over every participant
for (i in responses$ID){
    #create temporary data.frame with only participant "i"s responses
    data <- subset(responses, ID == i)
    #loop over each scale and store the relevant response numbers
    for (s in scales){
        relevantResponses <- scales[c(s)]
        #create a temporary storage for the total of each scale
        runningScore <- 0
        #index each response and add it to the total
        for (r in relevantResponses){
             runningScore <- runningScore + data[1,r]
```

However I am getting the error:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(data, 1, r) : 
  undefined columns selected
```

Is there a better way of doing the indexing rather than the nested loops?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `rowSums` loop over the `key` data columns with `lapply`, extract the 'responses' numeric columns based on the index, get the `rowSums` convert the `list` to `data.frame` and `cbind` with the first column of 'responses'

```
cbind(responses[1], data.frame(lapply(key, 
     function(x) rowSums(responses[-1][, na.omit(x)], na.rm = TRUE))))
```

-output

```
#  ID X Y Z
#1 A1 4 4 3
#2 B2 4 4 1
#3 C3 5 8 6
```

---

Or with `tidyverse`

```
imap(key, ~ responses %>%
     transmute(ID, !!.y :=  rowSums(select(cur_data()[-1], na.omit(.x)),
          na.rm = TRUE))) %>% 
     reduce(inner_join)
```

-output

```
#  ID X Y Z
#1 A1 4 4 3
#2 B2 4 4 1
#3 C3 5 8 6
```

---

Or another option is `mutate` with `across`

```
key %>%
   mutate(across(everything(), 
       ~ rowSums(responses[-1][na.omit(.)], na.rm = TRUE)), 
          ID = responses$ID, .before = 1)
#  ID X Y Z
#1 A1 4 4 3
#2 B2 4 4 1
#3 C3 5 8 6
```

#### data

```
responses <- structure(list(ID = c("A1", "B2", "C3"), X1 = c(1L, 0L, 3L), 
    X2 = c(1L, 1L, 3L), X3 = c(2L, 3L, 2L), X4 = c(1L, 0L, 0L
    )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

key <- structure(list(X = 2:4, Y = 1:3, Z = c(1L, 2L, 4L)), class = "data.frame",
   row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: My "key" data.frame has NA's in it (some scales use more responses). I think this is causing an "undefined columns" error. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way of dealing with this problem. I just wanted to challenge myself with my favorite choice of solution and this is not as concise and brilliant as the ones proposed by dear @akrun. Here is to him who taught me how to do it with with `purrr` family of functions:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

responses %>% 
  select(X1:X4) %>% 
  pmap_dfr(., ~ map_dfc(1:length(key), function(x) sum(c(...)[key[, x]]))) %>%
  bind_cols(responses$ID) %>%
  set_names(c("x", "y", "z", "ID")) %>% 
  relocate(ID)

  ID        x     y     z
  <chr> <int> <int> <int>
1 A1        4     4     3
2 B2        4     4     1
3 C3        5     8     6
```

There are two more concise approaches proposed by dear @akrun I would like to add to here. One with `rowSums` function and the other with `reduce` from `purrr` package. Just keep in mind that when we apply `+` function with reduce on a data frame, it will be applied on every row and collapsed it into a single element:

```
map_dfc(key, ~ responses[-1][.x] %>% rowSums())

# A tibble: 3 x 3
      X     Y     Z
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     4     4     3
2     4     4     1
3     5     8     6
```

And with `reduce`:

```
map_dfc(key, ~ responses[-1][.x] %>% reduce(`+`))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
      X     Y     Z
  <int> <int> <int>
1     4     4     3
2     4     4     1
3     5     8     6
```

Comment: I think the rowSums approach is more direct or you could use `reduce` with `+` i.e. `map_dfc(key, ~ responses[-1][.x] %>% reduce(`+`))`

Comment: You are very right as always. Let me try that approach now as I'm practicing on my `reduce` function skills nowadays haha.